# Automatically connect to PPTP VPN on Ubuntu Server 22.10 (No GUI)

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I am trying to have my Ubuntu Server machine connect automatically to a PPTP VPN on reboot.
Right now I have to connect manually using:

```
pppd call MyVPN
```

Ideally, I would also want it to attempt to reconnect automatically if connection is lost.

If the server doesn't connect to the VPN, I have no way of accessing the machine remotely.
All the guides when I look for an answer are based on Ubuntu with GUI.